# If two random variables are equal, prove or disprove that they are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Say $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $P(X=Y)=1.$ I think they are independent.

Here is how I'm thinking about it. Let $k$ be a point where $X$ and $Y$ would occur. $$P(X=k, Y=k)=P(X=Y)=1=P(X=k)*P(Y=k).$$ Is there something wrong with my proof? Thanks!

Comment: This goes totally against intuition and it can be easily disproved technically.

Comment: I believe the only way where $X$ is independent of itself is when $X$ is almost surely a constant. Indeed, you have for any Borel set $P(X \in B) = P(X \in B)^2$ so $P(X \in B)$ is either zero or one. Now consider $B = B(b) = (-\infty, b]$ for some real $b.$ Let $c$ be the infimum of the $b$ such that $P(X \in B) = 1$ (such set of $b$ is clearly not empty since $X$ is finite with probabiltiy one), it follows easily that $P(X = c) = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: Take $Y = X$. $X$ is certainly not independent of $X$! (Explanation below)

Flaw in proof: To show $X,Y$ are independent, you need to show that **for any** $x,y$, $P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y)$.

It is not enough to consider only a point $k$ where $P(X=k) = 1$.

Under your assumption that $P(X=Y) = 1$, we have
$P(X=x,Y=y) = 0$ if $x \neq y$. But $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y = y)$ need not be zero.

Comment: I see. So they are actually not independent because X and Y can always take on the same value? I'm just a little confused because intuitively taking the same values does not convey anything about independence.

Comment: So I guess the correct wording is "X and Y could be independent"?

Comment: @Paul726 When $X=Y$ then the event of $\{X=x\}$ is the event of $\{X=x,Y=x\}$ then $$\mathsf P(X=x, Y=x)=\mathsf P(X=x)$$.So if $0<\mathsf P(X=x)<1$ clearly $$\mathsf P(X=x,Y=x)\neq \mathsf P(X=x)~\mathsf P(Y=y)$$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think of random variables $X$ and $Y$ being independent is "Does knowing the value of $X$ tell me anything about the value of $Y$?"

If knowing something about $X$ also gives you knowledge about $Y$, or vice versa, then they are *not* independent since they *depend* on each other somehow.

So if $P(X = Y) = 1$, then knowing the value of $X$ gives you almost perfect information about the value of $Y$, and hence they are not independent (except for some degenerate cases).

Comment: While I learnt this way of understanding stochastic independence, I grew up and discarded it later. _It is not_ the knowledge of $X$ to infer knowledge of $Y$ but rather that knowing values of $X$ affect the _probabilities_ of $Y.$ This is specially critical in multivariate analyses where many mistakes are done based on this _flawed_ intuition. In multivariate analysis is not uncommon to find $X = g(Z)$ and $Y = h(Z)$ for some random object $Z$ and yet $X$ and $Y$ are independent (for instance, $Z = (Z_1, Z_2)$ is a bivariate standard normal and $X = Z_1-Z_2,$ $Y = Z_1+Z_2$)....

Comment: (continuing the example, if you know $X = 0,$ then you know $Y$ is supported on the diagonal, yet $X$ and $Y$ are independent, meaning that despite you know something of $Y$ you cannot infer anything about its stochastic properties.)

Comment: That's fair, I hope it's ok for a lay explanation though.